# Is the ball turret on the F7C-M Super Hornet movable in Star Citizen?

Tags: star-citizen

Is the ball turret on the F7C-M Super Hornet already movable in the Star Citizen?

[image]

If yes, how do you control it?

Comment: @kalina, Thanks for the edit. I couldn't add the star-citizen tag because I didn't have enough reputation to create a new tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the day your answer was posted, no, the turret was not animated in any way. If you wanted to move the turret you would need to enable it in the game code.

Today, since Arena Commander is out, the turret moves so it can shoot at its target.